# broadcasting isuue with ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (21,) (18,)

Tags: numpy

I want to add aa and bb together

```
cc = np.asarray([5, 6, 7])
aa = np.arange(len(cc)).repeat(cc)
bb = np.random.randn(len(cc) * 7)
# this runs too slow is there another way ? 
cc = dd[:,None] + vv
bb = torch.flatten(cc)
```

but whenever I apply it to my model I get `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (21,) (18,)`

any help is appreciate it

Comment: What's the full error message?  Did you look at `aa` and `bb`?  Do their shapes make sense to you.

Comment: their shapes are understandable given I'm repeating the values of cc but how to broadcast them together, I edit it my answer but this runs too slow, is there a better way?

Comment: `aa[:,None]+bb` is THE way to broadcast the two arrays, making a (18,21) shape.